# Android collection widget update asynchronously

Tags: android, asynchronous, widget, retrofit

I have a collection widget. My data comes from api call. I am using retrofit with javarx.

Everything works fine if I update list synchronously:

```
@Override
public void onDataSetChanged() {
    tasks.add(getTask());
}
```

However, I need to update them asynchronously because it is difficult to execute api method synchronously.

Is there a way to notify view factory that new data comes like this:

```
@Override
public void onDataSetChanged() {
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> params = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>() {{
        put("data", "1");
    }};


Repository.provideRepository(api)
        .getCampaignsList(params)
        .subscribe(taskList -> {
            tasks.clear();
            tasks.addAll(taskList);
            notifyUpdateItems(); // something like this
        });
}
```

Comment: You can make something like: Download your data in IntentService, and after that fetch data from database in your widget. It's just a most popular pattern to update widget like you want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I didn't know that JavaRx can execute on the same thread. The solution is just

```
Repository.provideRepository(api)
        .getCampaignsList(params)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.immediate())
        .observeOn(Schedulers.immediate())
        .subscribe(taskList -> {
            tasks.clear();
            tasks.addAll(taskList);
            notifyUpdateItems(); // something like this
        });
```